# Ubuntu terminal text does not show but I can enter commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I recently uninstalled mono packages and may have removed something else I shouldn't have.  I tried using apt-get to remove gnome-terminal and reinstall it, but I still see no text in terminal.  I'm using xterm for now, which works fine, but I would rather have the option of using terminal.

Comment: try typing "reset" in terminal.

Comment: It was the font color being the same and the background color. :|  Not sure how it got that way.

Answer (score 0):

this answer could help more to the OP, with a *step-by-step* guide to provide the solution.

> **Use colors from your system theme**
>
> 1. Select Edit ▸ Profile Preferences ▸ Colours.
> 2. Check Use colors from system theme. The changes will be applied automatically.

*Or*

> **Built-in schemes**
>
> 3. **Make sure that Use colors from system theme is unchecked**. Choose the desired color scheme from Built-in schemes, or select your desired color using Palette. Color scheme choicesvare applied automatically.

---

[image: Editing Gnome Terminal Profile]

Documentation [Here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-colors.html.en)

---

If doesn't help you should do a terminal initialization using `reset` command.

[Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset)